# Should I structure types with different precision levels in a hierarchy?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, naming-conventions

I'm writing a library with structures of varying precision level, such as a point with integer coordinates and a point with floating-point coordinates. .NET uses `Point` for its integral structure, and `PointF` for the floating-point variant, but I recently stumbled across Java's equivalent, which uses `Point` and a nested `Point.Double`.

I like the idea of defining types like this:

```
struct Point {
    // integral implementation

    public struct Double {
         // double floating-point implementation
    }
    public struct Long {
         // 64-bit implementation
    }
    // etc..
}
```

What I don't like is redefining "Double" and "Long" inside the parent type. Has anyone used this pattern and found any more problems that arise from it? Or should I stick with `Point`, `PointD`, & `PointL`?

Comment: Just to state the obvious, you cannot inherit from a struct, so you'd *have* to take the MS approach.

Comment: @tcarvin - Oops, I meant nested class, not subclass. The posted sample code *is* valid in C#.

Comment: There is a big difference between these if that is a struct or a class.  Your code sample is a struct and therefore *both* Point.Double and Point.Long exists (take up memory) when the user has a variable of type Point.  At least with classes you can prevent that.

Comment: @tcarvin - They are not fields, they are nested classes. They're simply nested definitions, **not** nested instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I despise this idea. I think of nested classes as implementation details of the containing class, and a point with `double` fields is not an implementation detail of a point with `int` fields. Nested classes are used for encapsulating implementation details that do not make sense outside of their containing class. Here, that is just not the case. Don't do this.

Also, I don't see why you just wouldn't go with the naming convention:

```
struct Int32Point 
struct Int64Point 
struct SinglePoint
struct DoublePoint
```

Comment: What if I were to name them `Point.Int32`, `Point.Double`, etc. That seems to follow the "implementation detail" convention you've described.

Comment: I'm a little confused by "implementation detail" then, because it seems like you have different "implementations" of `Point` as subclasses.

Comment: @Dan Rasmussen: Ah, okay. First, those aren't subclasses, they are nested classes. Second "implementation detail" refers to behavior/code that not defined by the specification the code is written to, but rather is particular to the implementation. If you and I both write implementations of `IStack<T>`, our implementations will likely differ and the differences are implementation details. A simple example is the name of the private backing field for auto-properties. That is an implementation detail (it's not in the spec) and will differ from Mono to Microsoft's implementation of .NET.

Comment: @Dan Rasmussen: So, the most common usage of nested classes is as an implementation detail of the containing class. And that is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Sorry about the subclass/nested class mix-up.